# How to search for Opcode 0xFF25 in IDA Pro?

Tags: reverse-engineering, ida

I want to search for opcodes in IDA Pro like the following:

```
0xFF25
```

How can I do that?

Comment: The best place to ask RE questions is on [reverseengineering.stackexchange.com](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

In the "search" menu, click "sequence of bytes..." or use the default hotkey which is Alt+B.

Choose the hex radio button and type in your bytes **ff 25** remembering that you will have to get the byte ordering correct for whatever type of file you are disassembling.

If you want to find all instances of that opcode, make sure to check the "Find all occurrences" button.